# How to make symbol of mark clickable once the mouse pointer hover it in vega

Tags: json, charts, visualization, vega

I have a vega horizontal bar chart with slider changing dynamically the value on xaxis .

[The code](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykSALJQBWENgDsQAGhAB3GgBN6aAOwAGNTPg0yWNAFZNIHEgUKa4sgZkQd4pABsIaANqh7COGhBQGAJz84cUwATTgkPzVpEGJHBi9UAGZDGQlXUDhSYOd0FwABGCRxBQc4NVQENgYIOAU2WXEpAAJ5YvqKqpqGHABdJoA+Fos62Q7qxDZSAEJo7oUkTASfByQEHAAKC1I-THWAcgAPPeaoFbX1g-WASmbNIaUYK5u73wCg0PC-AEYAWn0rkAAXx6gKk7lWS1egWCYQiX2isQc8VUGlSklQbhAmXeORA+UKxVKXzGNRGjSGbVGlXG3T6g1aIxJE2msxw80W3lOqw2WzgO32RxOZw2lxuTSh71hkT+zXkDyeUglMM+ahlTXUagBwOBNigjjgOUxHiWAE9opgTTglkwigpon4imQltpdJhonVkBZXF8QWCQMbvAdzZalg4LJ97Y6lnLlDIPUgvRjNBqQT0ZMg-ABrQ3gzzeQJQTBRGQWq35uCF6JBKBsBQJUBzBb1kBm1CgaD67xmmSI5HoKKgjBwHR6NsgDulLvRG3FNBfVIAMwXNTdqB+X0HQbHE6WQZsdkc3gHMgOACY0O29ZP0HvxweHJz-NCPhFjyAFzQHA+x72lgBiNQAA4BAUABOfQgRkD8vwAeRMKA6FbUBfznQFBxgSY+Qvd9PwcOCkAQi1sJQ1A1EofQ0LQv0A3QAtMHhEsQ3LSsZGrWtm0bDkxyQ8cr1NBE4iWN8XVHS9O3QbsQBnO1UHnEA2CXFc0HXTdsJ3QNolsMh7G-Hwn0lFVIJAM81L4jT920w90A1IzoO-ZDBO8ACoDgOAmCYWzcPwwieJIjd0MwvxsLs7zEOIxzSPIyjQVzZ1bVKYsQFLJYIBNBAmDYB9WPEGs62w94sO40zxOMgSkQSIwFOXOBVx+FRBwgQoyx-CKkr8GhHVKH4ySM2wAC9mxIgQNAazA-DYTNBtagCNCMrcxOvUqoJoOAHBkls3xM7czJvaIP1W9aTXhUbxsmgB1RRlBa8q0DIijB045t5t4krby0nTHzeZVXyBALtmC3Dwpu9BSkqHKYBoJc0kHV4xCC66+2MNgLEWILor9ZLvEWA43Wy3LmwK+HQF8iKflPNRBwXCRMAAZRoAagb7L4ADZKeps7h1dRnrUyu1KcBhGUsWVamBuwdHDsbnvFKBc3UHG0ajDcQpuBkAEEUEovHFyxrwc4GflAimoLYPxkFXaRKFPZwHrZJtsOx1d23vbwqdNhZ1iVF9IikPZKC+Bc9i1E9isWt7nfQT2pQHSi0x8CQPysNs0KAA)

When the mouse pointer hover the slider (the triangle symbol) nothing happens initially and it is not possible to move the slider .
In order to slide it left or right , first I need to click on it and only after that it is possible to do the sliding .

[image]

The expected behavior is to covert the mouse pointer to hand and make the slider move directly once hover is happening .

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the mark a fill on enter.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "width": 700,
  "height": 50,
  "padding": 5,
  "signals": [
    {
      "name": "currentYear0",
      "value": 350,
      "on": [
        {
          "events": "[@handle0:mousedown, window:mouseup] > window:mousemove!",
          "update": "clamp(invert('x', clamp(x(), 0, width)),0, currentYear1-5)"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "currentYear1",
      "value": 700,
      "on": [
        {
          "events": "[@handle1:mousedown, window:mouseup] > window:mousemove!",
          "update": "clamp(invert('x', clamp(x(), currentYear0-5, width)),currentYear0-5, 700)"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "scales": [
    {"name": "y", "type": "band", "range": "height", "domain": [1]},
    {"name": "x", "type": "linear", "range": "width", "domain": [0, 700]}
  ],
  "marks": [
    {
      "name": "rect0",
      "type": "rect",
      "encode": {
        "update": {
          "y": {"scale": "y", "value": "0"},
          "height": {"scale": "y", "band": 1, "offset": -1},
          "x": {"scale": "x", "signal": "0"},
          "x2": {"scale": "x", "signal": "currentYear0"},
          "fill": {"value": "#084d95"},
          "fillOpacity": {"value": 1}
        },
        "hover": {"fillOpacity": {"value": 0.5}}
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "rect1",
      "type": "rect",
      "encode": {
        "update": {
          "y": {"scale": "y", "value": "0"},
          "height": {"scale": "y", "band": 1, "offset": -1},
          "x": {"scale": "x", "signal": "currentYear0"},
          "x2": {"scale": "x", "signal": "700"},
          "fill": {"value": "#0ceebb"},
          "fillOpacity": {"value": 1}
        },
        "hover": {"fillOpacity": {"value": 0.5}}
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "handle0",
      "type": "symbol",
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "y": {"scale": "x", "value": 0, "offset": -7},
          "shape": {"value": "triangle-down"},
          "size": {"value": 400},
          "stroke": {"value": "#000"},
          "x": {"scale": "x", "field": "y0"},
          "x2": {"scale": "x", "field": "y1"},
          "strokeWidth": {"value": 0.5},
           "fill": {"value": "red"}
        },
        "update": {"x": {"scale": "x", "signal": "currentYear0"}},
        "hover": {
          "fill": {"value": "lemonchiffon"},
          "cursor": {"value": "pointer"}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "text",
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "y": {"value": -20},
          "fontSize": {"value": 16},
          "fontWeight": {"value": "bold"},
          "fill": {"value": "steelblue"},
          "align": {"value": "left"},
          "baseline": {"value": "middle"},
          "angle": {"value": -90},
          "format": ",.2s"
        },
        "update": {
          "text": {"signal": "format(currentYear0,'.1f')"},
          "x": {"scale": "x", "signal": "currentYear0"}
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "config": {}
}
```